# Flutter - Edge and Chrome pages always appear blank when not running the given standard main file

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, dart

every time I run a debug session (may it be on chrome or on edge) the page appears entirely blank, but no errors are thrown.

So far I´ve tried:

- reducing the code to a minimum to exclude errors in the widgets code
- running on different devices
- running via flutter run -d chrome --web-port=8080 --web-hostname=the value of IPv4 Address
- adding localhost to my "safe-list" on my antivirus

Here you can see my flutter doctor -v:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1237], locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (3 months ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • android-studio-dir = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[√] VS Code (version 1.60.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.27.0

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 94.0.4606.61
    • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 94.0.992.38

• No issues found!
```

Also my code in textform:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TestingWidget());
}

class TestingWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Performing test on testwidget.dart");
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(body: Text("Testwidget") //MethodWidget(),
            )
        //home: Text("test")
        );
  }
}
```

I am sorry if I provided anything in the wrong way, it is my first time writing on stackoverflow.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

I just had this issue, and It turned out to be a poor internet connection, ran out of subscription in the middle of building the application. Restored my internet and it built successfully

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31432494)